# Limiting a user to a single request at one time GAE datastore

Tags: python, ajax, google-app-engine, request, webapp2

> **Question**

Suppose a user makes a vote on a question (like SO). A `makeVote` ajax request is sent to the server. The current question (`currentQ`) and the user (`currentUser`) is available to the server from the url and current session. How do you prevent the user from sending multiple requests and voting more than once at a single time?

> **My faulty solution**

**Ajax Request**

```
function voteUp(){
    $.ajax({url: "servertools/py/vote?quid="+getUrlParameter('quid')+"&type=quid&a=1", success: function(result){
        $("#questionVotes").html(result);
    }});
```

**Python Request Handler (webapp2)**

(My `Student` Class has a Boolean Property `isVoting` which is `False` by default)

```
currentUser = Student.query(Student.user_id == self.session.get('dbid')).get()
currentQ  = Question.query(Question.qid == self.request.get('quid')).get()

if currentUser.isVoting: # if another request is active
    # write unchanged votes 
    return

# otherwise, no other request is active
currentUser.isVoting = True # set request to currently active. Unsafe for other requests.
currentUser.put()
# perform vote accordingly
currentUser.isVoting = False # current request complete. set request to inactive. Safe for other requests.
currentUser.put()
```

> **Problem**

`if currentUser.isVoting:` is never `True`

Comment: Read up on strategies such as roll forward trasnactions. See http://blog.notdot.net/2009/9/Distributed-Transactions-on-App-Engine  using this strategy you can create a transaction entity for each user which can be used to limit voting to a single vote per user.

Answer (score 0):

When you do the get() you are creating a new instance of the user class so that the isVoting is set to false and never remember that he has already voted on that question.

Additionally, each question should have a hasVoted indicator. Otherwise, you could have him indicated as voted already when you are processing a different question.

You would need to create a list of all "current users" with the state that you want them kept in. Then when you create a new instance of current user, (which sets the voting state to false) you need to check that list for the user ID and update the state indicators. Otherwise, when the "currrent user" finishes, you will free the class instance, resetting it to false if the user returns to vote again.

You should be doing this in the get() method for both the user and the question so that you can verify that the current question has not already been voted on. In your code, you should have a get() option for the has voted state on that question.

Note that you should not set the class variables directly, but create methods that will reference the class variable within the class.